# noUiSlider does not appear on screen

Tags: javascript, html, nouislider

I'm using Materialize CSS to build a form and would like to use the noUiSlider with two handles that they have as an example on their website (http://materializecss.com/forms.html). When I add the includes for noUiSlider (JS and CSS) as well as the code they have from the example, I am unable to produce the slider. Here's my JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/omarrida/6zsbpwr4/

HTML:

```
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/9.0.0/nouislider.min.css' rel="stylesheet">
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/9.0.0/nouislider.js'></script>

<div id="test5" class="noUiSlider" style="height: 50px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

JS:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('test5');
  noUiSlider.create(slider, {
   start: [20, 80],
   connect: true,
   step: 1,
   range: {
     'min': 0,
     'max': 100
   },
   format: wNumb({
     decimals: 0
   })
  });
```

I've been wrestling with this for a while so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the js code placed?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean... it's placed in the JS section of the Fiddle.

Comment: Your script is runnin onLoad so it's fine, but if you check the console you will see `Uncaught ReferenceError: wNumb is not defined` So the issue is with wNumb not noUiSlider

Comment: Yeah just notice that in the console, console is your friend.

Comment: Wow. I just imported the CDNJS for wNumb and *tada* - it worked. Did I miss something in noUiSlider's documentation that required importing wNumb?

Comment: Also, since I'm still a newbie, thanks for the heads up on console. You probably saved me a few unnecessary posts in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @GillesC noted, the issue was with wNumb and not with noUiSlider. By simply importing the CDNJS for wNumb, the issue was resolved. Here is the new fiddle if anyone is interested.

https://jsfiddle.net/omarrida/6zsbpwr4/2/

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wnumb/1.0.4/wNumb.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Cheers! Glad I could help.